# Article défini ou indéfini devant un nom d'animal

Tags: articles

Les Français ont ce proverbe au sujet des hirondelles :

> *Une* hirondelle ne fait pas le printemps.

Néanmoins, l'article défini est utilisé devant le nom dans cette deuxième phrase.

> [*L*'hirondelle annonce soit le printemps soit l'automne.](https://scontent-hkg3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t31.0-8/s720x720/11134047_954730637879706_7649386111746026046_o.png)

Pourquoi met-on un article indéfini pour la première phrase mais défini pour la deuxième ?  Dans les deux cas, j'ai l'impression que l'article « une »   donne au nom « hirondelle » une valeur générale.

P.S. Mon livre de grammaire française : *Grammaire Progressive du Français (Avancé)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'article défini au singulier peut avoir un sens général, la deuxième phrase peut être remplacée par :

> Les hirondelles annoncent soit le printemps soit l'automne.

Dans la première phrase, il ne s'agit pas de l'article indéfini, mais de l'adjectif numéral, c'est-à-dire la quantité « 1 ».
On pourrait dire :

> Une seule hirondelle ne suffit pas à faire le printemps.

C'est-à-dire qu'il ne faut pas juger trop vite d'une situation.

Comment: Voici un exemple d'un article *indéfini* au singulier ayant un sens général (copié de mon livre) :

> Un chien a besion d'avoir un maître.

Comment peut-on distinguer ces deux articles au singulier ?

Answer (score 4):

*Une* est pour moi le nombre ici et pas l'article, voir une seule hirondelle ne suffit pas pour dire que le printemps est arrivé, on pourrait compléter la phrase par *deux non plus*.

Mais il y a bien une ambiguïté qui n'est résolue que par le contexte et le sens que l'on veut donner.  Si plutôt que de penser qu'il faut qu'elle soit en nombre suffisant pour que ce soit significatif comme je le fais, on pense qu'il faut qu'elle soit d'une espèce particulière et qu'il faille donc compléter par *mais les hirondelles noires de Bordurie bien*, le *une* serait bien l'article indéfini.

Lors de la rédaction, si on cherche à éviter l’ambiguïté, on va utiliser des expressions comme *une seule*, ou *une hirondelle quelconque*.

Comment: Personnellement je sens une subtilité où "une" veut dire "n'importe quelle", alors que "l'hirondelle" parle de la capacité de l’espèce... non ?

Comment: Oui.  Mais dans le proverbe, je perçois fortement un nombre.  P.e. je pourrais lui ajouter _deux non plus d'ailleurs_ sans problème ce qui ne serait pas le cas si _une_ signifiait _n'importe quelle_.

Comment: En effet, ça dépend de comment on lit la phrase. Subtile tout ça... !